# My code is not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert some data from form to database . I know how to retrieve values but the thing is that I need to insert the data into a certain order.
I have a TIMETABLE with user insert TIME and SUBJECTS , so I need to insert SUBJECT values corresponding to the TIME .

```
    $Times      = $_POST['Time'];
    $Subject    = $_POST['Subject'];
    $Year       = "2013-2017";
    $Dept       = "CSE";
    $Tutor      = "Vishnu";
    $con        = $this->db_con();
    $count      = count($Subject);

    foreach ($Times as $Timings) {
        for ($i=0;$i<count($Subject);$i++) {
            $ins_tmtbl  = $con->prepare("insert into time_table (Department,Year,Time,subject,Tutor_name) values(?,?,?,?,?)");
            $exe        = $ins_tmtbl->execute(array($Dept,$Year,$Timings,$Subject[$i],$Tutor));
        }
    }
```

And this is the HTML part ,

```
$number_of_prds = "10";

    for ($i=0;$i<=$wrkng_dys;$i++) {
        echo "<th>$days[$i]</th>";  
    }

    for ($j=1;$j<=2;$j++) {
        ?>

        <tr><th><div class="col-xs-2">
                    <input class="form-control input-lg" name="Time[]" id="inputlg" type="text" value="" style="width:120px; height:30px;"> 
                    </div></td>
        <?php   
        for ($s=1;$s<=count($days)-6;$s++) {
            ?>
            <td><div class="col-xs-2">
                    <?php  for ($i=0;$i<count($number_of_prds);$i++) { ?>
                    <input class="form-control input-lg" name="Subject[]" id="inputlg" type="text" value="" style="width:120px; height:30px;"> 
                    <?php } ?>
                    </div></td>
            <?php   
        }
        echo "</tr>";


    }
```

The result I am getting after inserting database like ,

```
10-11 sub1 sub2 sub3 sub4.....
11-12 sub1 sub2 sub3 sub4.....
```

I am expecting the result like ,
10-11 sub1 sub2 upto subjects corresponding to that hour and so on 
I am stucking with it any help will be really appreciated

Comment: try to set your counter like `<` to `<=`

Comment: actually I have two arrays , time & sub . so I need to insert first data from the first array and upto 8 datas from second array and second data from the first array and from 8 to 16 datas from second array and so on.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the Output

```
    $Times      = $_POST['Time'];
    $Subject    = $_POST['Subject'];
    $Day        = $_POST['Day'];
    $Year       = "2013-2017";
    $Dept       = "CSE";
    $Tutor      = "Vishnu";
    $con        = $this->db_con();
    $count      = count($Subject);
    $number_of_days = "5";

    $limit      = "5";
    for ($k=0;$k<$number_of_days;$k++) {
        for ($m=0;$m<$number_of_days;$m++) {
            if ($k == 0 ) {
                $j  = $m;   
            } 
            if ($k == 1) {
                $j  = $m+5; 
            }
            ${'arr'.$k} = array_slice($Subject,$j,$limit);  
            if ($m == 0) {
                $j = $limit+(5*$k);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    $time_limit     = 1;
    for ($n = 0;$n<$number_of_days;$n++) {
        ${'Time'.$n}    = array_slice($Times,$n,$time_limit);   
    }

    for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
        for ($j=0;$j<=5;$j++) {
            $ins_tmtbl  = $con->prepare("insert into time_table (Department,Year,Time,subject,Tutor_name,Day) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            $exe        = $ins_tmtbl->execute(array($Dept,$Year,${'Time' . $i}[0],${'arr' . $i}[$j],$Tutor,$Day[$j]));  
        }
    }
```

I dont know whether it's a good practice to code like this , but this code give me the output that I wanted

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have X `Time` variables and X*6 `Subject` variables, but no way to associate the two. What you need is a two-dimensional array on `Subject`:

```
<input class="form-control input-lg" name="Time[<?php echo $j;?>]" id="inputlg" type="text" value="" style="width:120px; height:30px;">

...

<input class="form-control input-lg" name="Subject[<?php echo $j;?>][]" id="inputlg" type="text" value="" style="width:120px; height:30px;">
```

Then you can associate the key for Time and Subject:

```
foreach ($Times as $key => $Timings) {
        for ($i=0;$i<count($Subject[$key]);$i++) {
            $ins_tmtbl  = $con->prepare("insert into time_table (Department,Year,Time,subject,Tutor_name) values(?,?,?,?,?)");
            $exe        = $ins_tmtbl->execute(array($Dept,$Year,$Timings,$Subject[$key][$i],$Tutor));
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you notice the extra double bracket in Subject name?

Comment: Yes eventhough it's not working as I expected , your code resulting like ,  time(11 am)   - sub(EM) , time(12 am) - (EC) etc . but I need result like    time(11 am) - sub(EM) sub(EC) upto subject corresponding to the  time

Comment: The first for loop is fine but the inner loop have the pblm , ie . I need to retrieve a certain number of datas from second array(subject) that is in inner loop and then go to outer loop and came back to inner loop and retrieve datas after we fetched the first time upto a certain limit and upto the outer for loop ends . Sorry for my bad English

Comment: No sure I follow. Your code is set up to insert multiple records for the same day - one for each Subject in the same day. Is that correct or not?

Comment: Yeah its for the same days but for all the periods I mean we have days from monday to friday and periods from 10 am to 5pm  so , the data actuallly inserting for monday , 10 am - 11 am and so on

Comment: Well, the code does not really care what you enter into Time fields, day, hour, or fruit names, it will create multiple records for that Time - one for each related Subject field. Based on your description and existing code I assumed that's what you wanted. If it's not, then please disregard my answer.

Comment: @ martynasma , finally I got the result that I wanted . I just slice the arrays(two arrays) with some limit so now I have around 8 subject(arrays) each contains around 9 datas and I also have 8 time(arrays) each array contains 1 data . So I chose time (arrays) as outer loop and subject (arrays) as inner loop . I dont know wether it is a good practice or not . any way thanks for the help

Comment: @ martynasma , I am very knew to Stack Overflow do I need to post the answer that I got

Comment: You can update your own question: add a new block with the final solution. Anyone else that is looking for the same solution will benefit from it.